# A Tiny Text File Read/Write class Implementation in C#

Tags: c#, performance, strings, file, stream

I am trying to implement a tiny text file read / write class `FileIO` in order to make the operations of reading / writing pure text files easily. The usage is like:

```
FileIO.Instance.FileWrite("TextFile1.txt", "This is a test1.");
FileIO.Instance.FileWrite("TextFile2.txt", "This is a test2.");
Console.WriteLine(FileIO.Instance.ReadTxTFile("TextFile1.txt", System.Text.Encoding.Default));
Console.WriteLine(FileIO.Instance.ReadTxTFile("TextFile2.txt", System.Text.Encoding.Default));
```

**The experimental implementation**

The experimental implementation of `FileIO` class is as below.

```
﻿﻿class FileIO
{
    public readonly static FileIO Instance = new FileIO();
    
    public void FileWrite(string filename, string inputString)
    {
        FileStream file_stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append);
        byte[] Input_data = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(inputString);
        file_stream.Write(Input_data, 0, Input_data.Length);
        file_stream.Flush();
        file_stream.Close();
    }
    
    public void FileWrite(string filename, string inputString, FileMode fileMode)
    {
        FileStream file_stream = new FileStream(filename, fileMode);
        byte[] Input_data = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(inputString);
        file_stream.Write(Input_data, 0, Input_data.Length);
        file_stream.Flush();
        file_stream.Close();
    }
    
    public void FileWrite(string filename, string inputString, FileMode fileMode, Encoding encoding)
    {
        FileStream file_stream = new FileStream(filename, fileMode);
        byte[] Input_data = encoding.GetBytes(inputString);
        file_stream.Write(Input_data, 0, Input_data.Length);
        file_stream.Flush();
        file_stream.Close();
    }

    public string ReadTxTFile(string filename, Encoding encoding)
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader textreader;
        string inputString;
        inputString = "";
        try
        {
            textreader = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename, encoding);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "";
            throw;
        }
        inputString = textreader.ReadToEnd();
        textreader.Close();
        return inputString;
    }
}
```

If there is any possible improvement about:

- Performance: including data reading/writing speed things
- The naming and readability
- Potential drawbacks of the implemented methods

, please let me know.

Comment: Why not use `File.ReadAllText` and `File.WriteAllText`? Also, you use classes that implement `IDisposable` yet you don't `Dispose()` of them. And why aren't you encapsulating their uses in a `using`?

Comment: @BCdotWEB Thank you for the comments. Do you mean that `Dispose()` method should be added? May I update the question?

Comment: Don't edit the code in the question but consider that fix to apply. [Using objects that implement IDisposable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects). And yes, methods `File.ReadAllText` and `File.WriteAllText` are already exist in .NET. Thus you don't need the code you wrote. [Learn what the `File` class can](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: @aepot OK, I see. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: AFAIK the code in the question can be updated as long as there isn't a review.

Comment: @JimmyHu Whether or not an explicit call to `Dispose()` is needed depends on the case. The best approach is to use a `using`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357258/does-using-statement-always-dispose-the-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Naming

- `FileIO`: The `File` class resides inside the `System.IO` namespace. `FileIO` is quite a misfortune chose of name. `TextFileWrapper`, `TextFileUtil` or `TextFileManager` would be a more appropriate name for this in my opinion.
- `FileWrite`: The general guidance is to start your methods with a verb. So, `WriteFile` would be a better name for this.
- `ReadTxtFile`: This name is a bit misleading. `txt` can be considered as a file extension, so the caller may no specify the filename as you expect.
- `inputString`: Please try to avoid [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation).

Please try to chase consistency (or symmetry).
Try to name your Read-Write method pair in the same fashion:

- `ReadTextFile`, `WriteTextFile`
- `ReadFile`, `WriteFile`
- or simply just `Read` and `Write`

Stuttering:

- Maybe it's just for me, but **File**IO.Instance.**File**Write seems too repetitive.
- `TextFileManager.Write` seems way more natural for me.

#### Robustness

Your implementation is quite naive. It does not deal with a lot of different cases:

- What if the `fileName` points to a non-existing file?
- What if the `inputString` is enormously large?
- What if one of the parameters is `null`?
- What if the file has been opened by another method and has not been closed yet?

Your implementation also relies on `Encoding.Default`, which is [computer specific](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default).
Which means you can end up in the following situation:

- `FileA.txt` has been written to the disk on MachineA
- `FileA.txt` has been copied from MachineA to MachineB

  - where the default encoding is different
- MachineB could not read `FileA.txt`

#### Thread-safety

- Your `instance` property does not make your class a singleton.

  - Please read thoroughly [Jon Skeet's guidance](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton).
- If you make your class a singleton you have to make sure that your operations are thread-safe.

  - Reading and writing the same file from different threads are handled in a proper way.
- As pointed out by others you have to do some clean-up as well.

  - To make sure that if something goes wrong then your file handles are closed properly.

#### Performance

- Try to take advantage of [async I/O](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/asynchronous-file-i-o)
- Try to take advantage of [ArrayPool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraypool-1?view=net-5.0) when you are calling the GetBytes method.

  - It has an [overload which accepts a byte array](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getbytes?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Encoding_GetBytes_System_Char___System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Byte___System_Int32_)
- As always, measure, measure and measure.